# VBA Excel inserting 0s infront of only certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with Values in Column A. Some of these Values are 1,5,535,W15. My issue is I need all values under 10 with a zero in front (e.g. 01,05), but no other values. I thought about formatting to text and doing a find and replace, but then all my numbers would be affected.

```
Columns("L").Replace What:="5", _'
                        Replacement:="05", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

My next thought was to make all my values 6 digits long, but The divisions would no longer upfeed into my companies system.

```
lastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Formula = "=Text(A1,"000000")
```

I have researched online, but I cant find a solution. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you, Matt

Comment: Why not just a numberformat of `00` or similar?  Or, if you are where the comma represents a decimal, `00.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can...

1. loop over the cells in the range
2. check if the cell contains a value
3. format the cell to text format if it does have a value
4. add a leading zero if the length of the value if 1 (e.g. single digit number)

Here is that code:

```
Public Sub AddingLeadingZeroIfSingleDigit()
    For Each c In Worksheets("Test").Columns("L").Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.NumberFormat = "@"
            If Len(CStr(c.Value)) = 1 Then
                c.Value = "0" & CStr(c.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You may need to adjust line 2 of the code to what is appropriate for your workbook. It currently is set to loop through the cells in column L of a worksheet named "Test".

Answer (score 0):

you can try the blow code. just add "'"& below the txt(a1,

Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Formula = "= *"'"*& Text(A1,"000000")

Answer (score 0):

you can validate the value of the cell first then you can format it

=IF(D23<10,TEXT(D23,"00"),D23)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this but seems to work :

```
Sub format_stuff()

Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, a
Set R2 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("L"))

For Each R1 In R2
    R1.NumberFormat = "00": a = R1.Text: R1.NumberFormat = "@": R1 = a
Next R1

End Sub
```